# Get file paths of selected files in RStudio Files pane

Tags: rstudio

I'm looking to get the file paths of selected files in the RStudio Files pane. I'm aware of `rstudioapi::executeCommand()` with commands in the [RStudio Server Pro Admin Guide](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/rstudio-ide-commands.html) that perform operations on selected files. I am seeking the absolute or relative path to selected files with respect to my R session's working directory.

In the image, the desired command would return a character vector with the selected file paths (relative paths are also fine):
`c("~/tmp/example/file1.R", "~/tmp/example/file2.R")`.

[image: example of selected files]